# spring-security is not part of the spring framework bom file

Tags: spring

As below xml file shows, spring security is not part of it. If their argument is that security is not part of the core module, my question is do we have a universal spring bom which has all the latest releases from spring.org

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Spring Framework (Bill of Materials)</name>
    <description>Spring Framework (Bill of Materials)</description>
    <url>
    https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework
    </url>
    <organization>
        <name>Spring IO</name>
        <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework</url>
    </organization>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>jhoeller</id>
            <name>Juergen Hoeller</name>
            <email>jhoeller@pivotal.io</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection>
    scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework
    </connection>
        <developerConnection>
    scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework
    </developerConnection>
        <url>
    https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework
    </url>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>Jira</system>
        <url>https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: not just security, spring-data not there too. probably many others